# Is there a way to create a top level window besides Form in .NET?

Tags: .net, winforms, window, form-control

Is there a way to create a Control that can display on the desktop without the use of Form?
For example, displaying a splash window?  I know that it's easy to create a splash window without any borders, etc. using Form.  But that's just an example.  I'd like to know if it's possible to create a top level window without all the baggage that comes with Form.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah it's possible, but you'll have to use some unmanaged API calls

Comment: Which may be fine.  I was thinking that a clever use of CreateParams could do it but just don't know what params :)